# Ruby on Rails and Microsoft SQL server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am asked to build a website with ruby on rails using a SQL server backend. I have only built sites with sqlite and postgres so I am a bit unsure. I did some digging and found a gem I can use.

activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

1) I am wondering if I use this plugin, does it mean I can still set up models and using active record searches such as where()

2) If users are pre created in the SQL through a EPRS system, will I still be able to integrate devise with that?

3) They are going to give me a bak file for the SQL server and asked me to set up my own sql server on my mac during the development phase, is this possible or do I have to pay for a microsoft sql server license to do this?

Thank you very much in advance, any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Rails against SQL Server plays against the strengths of both platforms. Weird thing for them to want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using this adapter in our project. Yes, you can use the 'normal way' to map you're models. Although we're only using it to read from the database I'm pretty sure the writes work the usual way as well.

If devise works strongly depends on the presence of the columns that devise expects.

Getting a MS Sql Server to run under OSX will be tricky enough. I'm not sure there are any trial licenses.